# Alternating between single and double quotes indefinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue dealing with multiple embedded/alternating quotes that I'm hoping someone can help with.  Here's the relevant code...

```
displayMessage(

    "post success!", 

    "<p style='margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px'>if you'd like to share your post...</p> 

    <a onclick='openSharePopup("+textA+","+numberA+","+numberB+")' style='cursor: pointer; font-size:16px'>
        share
    </a>"

);

function displayMessage(heading, text){
  $("#displayMessageHeadingDiv").html(heading);
  $("#displayMessageBodyDiv").html(text);
  $("#displayMessageParentDiv").css("display","block");
}
```

displayMessage() is called after the user successfully posts something on the website, and works perfectly unless "textA" contains an apostrophe (e.g. something like "Mike's Opinion")

The problem being (I think) is that although textA is encapsulated inside double quotes - those double quotes are already inside the single quotes of my onclick attribute - which itself is inside yet more double quotes  of the entire second argument of displayMessage.

I thought previously that alternating between single and double quotes could continue indefinitely but this example seems to suggest otherwise.  I've also experimented with these alternatives to break any quotes in textA but neither have worked...

```
textA = JSON.stringify(textA).replace(/&/, "&amp;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;");

textA = textA.replace("'","\'");
```

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is fundamentally wrong. Manually creating inline event handlers is almost always the wrong way to do it.

A better solution would be for example:

```
var shareLink = $( '<a>share</a>' )
                    .css({ cursor: 'pointer', 'font-size': '16px' })
                    .click( function() {
                            openSharePopup( textA , numberA, numberB );
                        });

var msg = $( "<p>if you'd like to share your post...</p>" )
              .css({ 'margin-top': '15px', 'margin-bottom': '15px' });

displayMessage( "post success!", shareLink.add( msg ) );

function displayMessage(heading, text){
  $("#displayMessageHeadingDiv").html(heading);
  $("#displayMessageBodyDiv").empty().append(text);
  $("#displayMessageParentDiv").show();
}
```

Essentially you should create the elements, add a click handler through the code, and add the elements directly to the container. This way you don't have to think about what kind of quotes to use and where.

(As another stylistic side note, it would be much better to use CSS classes to style the elements instead of inline styles.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Juhana - very happy to hear my approach was fundamentally wrong, and your rewrite has indeed completely solved the problem!!