# Jquery converting characters to ASCII code to sanitise html elements

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically creating tags and attributes using jquery

```
var mystring = "Let's do it";
var this element = $('<label onclick="$.fn.myshow(\''+ mystring +'\',false)"></label>');
```

and On click function is

```
$.fn.myshow() = function(arg1, arg2){
 alert(arg1); 
}
```

On-click would not get triggered here because of single quote in the text (Let's do it). Is there any way to replace such characters by ASCII codes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternating between single and double quotes indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35013034/alternating-between-single-and-double-quotes-indefinitely)

Comment: Is there a reason you resort to `onclick` attributes instead of event listeners?

Comment: I think you should reconsider this whole approach; there a multiple better ways to achieve something similar

Comment: Using `$.fn.someMethod()` for inline onclick makes no sense at all

Comment: I need to make sure attributes are set without characters like quotes.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use inline `onclick` or manually insert the string into html strings. or worry about escaping  if you do something like:

```js
$.fn.myshow = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      alert($(this).data('string'));
    })
  })

}


var mystring = "Let's do it";
var $element = $('<label>',{text:'click me'}).data('string', mystring).myshow();



$element.appendTo('body')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or  even simpler version without using the `$.fn` plugin method

```js
var mystring = "Let's do it";

$('<label>',{text:'click me'}).click(function(){
   alert(mystring)
}).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```